# Google Plus not working on website

Tags: javascript, html, google-plus, google-plus-one

I initially created a Google Plus One button, copied the javascript code, and pasted it into my website. The button was working fine. A few weeks later, the button didn't appear. I tried in multiple browsers, but only blank space showed up where the button is supposed to be. I tried reinstalling, to no avail.

Since I use WordPress for my website, I decided to take the HTML and JavaScript code out and install ShareThis on the homepage and add the Plus One button to it. It doesn't even show up there. You can see it at http://www.wwwbuildawebsite.com/. It is supposed to be between the Facebook Like and Pinterest. However, I see it appearing on another page of my website, http://wwwbuildawebsite.com/tutorials/index.html.

In the rest of my posts, blank space shows up. You can click on any of the links in the Tutorials Page. The sharebar appears at the left; the Google Plus One button is supposed to appear first, before Twitter.

Comment: The underlying HTML/iframe is there, chekc the source.  Something wrong with your integration.

Comment: It works fine in other pages where it is integrated the same way. For some reason, it appears only sometimes, and sometimes not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem seems to be that you are including mootools-1.2.3 which overwrites the JSON object provided by the browser.  The sharethis library fails when trying to call JSON.parse which then fails to render the G+ button.

You could:

1) Upgrade to mootools 2.0 or newer (see https://mootools.lighthouseapp.com/projects/2706-mootools/tickets/741-google-friend-connect-js-api-with-mootools#ticket-741-4)

2) Place your call to asynchronously load plusone.js after you load mootools:

```
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://www.wwwbuildawebsite.com/wp-content/plugins/superslider/js/mootools-1.2.3-core-yc.js?ver=1.2.3'></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
  (function() {
    var po = document.createElement('script'); po.type = 'text/javascript'; po.async = true;
    po.src = 'https://apis.google.com/js/plusone.js';
    var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; s.parentNode.insertBefore(po, s);
  })();
</script>
```

This will re-instate the JSON.parse function after it is overwritten.

3) Manually alias the functions:

```
JSON.parse = JSON.decode;
JSON.stringify = JSON.encode;
```

Comment: I didn't need the plugins so I removed them altogether. The Google Plus One Button works perfectly. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

Your page calls an undefined function `appendCodeColorer` from the body of the `onLoad` event handler.  This prevents the `onLoad` event handler from completing successfully.

The iframe containing your Google plus one button is initially rendered with the CSS styles:

```
position: absolute;
top: -10000px;
```

The button is then made visible during `onLoad`. If `onLoad` does not complete, it will remain invisible.

Comment: javascript function 'appendCodeColorer' is defined though. Command (or Control) + F ---Search 'appendCodeColorer'

Comment: The script block defining appendCodeColorer is declared type="javascript" which is incorrect and so doesn't create the function.  It should be type="text/javascript".

Comment: That is right...(how dumb of me). I took the entire function out and removed it from the onLoad event handler altogether. After emptying cache and cookies the Google Plus One button still won't show up.

Comment: Hmmm.. that undefined function appears to have been a distraction.  It was the fact that I was pausing execution in the javascript debugger which was allowing the +1 button to show up successfully.